# Failed to create the configuration database in SharePoint 2016

Tags: configuration, 2016

While installing SharePoint 2016, I face below error in Configuration Wizard

> Failed to create the configuration database.
>
> An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown

**Error log:**

> 05/04/2016 15:56:16  11  INF                                    Now
>   joining to farm at server XXX  database SharePoint_Config_2016
>   05/04/2016 15:56:16  11  INF
>   Entering function Command.this[string key] 05/04/2016 15:56:16  11 
>   INF                                      Entering function
>   CommandCollectionBase.Get 05/04/2016 15:56:16  11  INF
>   Found value in collection for key localserverrole 05/04/2016 15:56:16 
>   11  INF                                      Leaving function
>   CommandCollectionBase.Get 05/04/2016 15:56:16  11  INF
>   Found parameter localserverrole in collection 05/04/2016 15:56:16  11 
>   INF                                    Leaving function
>   Command.this[string key] 05/04/2016 15:56:16  11  INF
>   The parameter localserverrole is chosen, so returning the value as
>   Application 05/04/2016 15:59:35  11  ERR
>   Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception  05/04/2016
>   15:59:35  11  ERR                                    Exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: One or more types
>   failed to load. Please refer to the upgrade log for more details.
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions() 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_Actions()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionBeforeMajorVersion(Type
>   typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteSequence.get_PreviousTargetSchemaVersion()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateSequencesTable(StringBuilder
>   sqlstr, Boolean siteSequence)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ConstructSiteNeedsUpgradeQuery(Guid
>   siteId)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.GetSiteNeedsUpgrade(SPUpgradeSession
>   session, SPContentDatabase database, Dictionary`2&
>   dictSitesNeedUpgrade, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedFeatureUpgrade)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,
>   Boolean bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,
>   SPDelegateManager delegateManager)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalUpgradeStatus()

Comment: In other cases, You should install WCF Services Tools using prerequisites installer Check the details at **[SharePoint 2016: Failed to create the configuration database. An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-failed-to-create-the-configuration-database-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The message says it all - **"Failed to connect to the configuration
>   database."**
>
> You can click on the PSCDiagnostics log file to get more insights
>   related to this error.
>
> Check the account which you are using to connect to SQL Server
>   instance, make sure it has the required permissions/roles to create
>   configuration database -
>
> 1. Dbcreator
> 2. SysAdmin
> 3. SecurityAdmin
>
> Once the correct permissions are set, re-run the Product Configuration
>   Wizard and it should complete without any issues.

**UPDATED :- You can follow steps mentioned in below given URL**

[SharePoint Server 2016 Installation step by step](http://mstechtalk.com/sharepoint-server-2016-installation-step-by-step/)

Comment: Yes i given all permissions mentinoed above

Comment: Please provide the entire error from log file. So i can identify & help you.

Comment: is MS Office installed on your machine? If yes than please uninstall it & then try.

Comment: No There is no Ms-office installed in this sharepoint server

Comment: On database level, please also assign to the user (the one you are running the wizard with), the roles "dbcreator" and "securityadmin". If you didn't do that.

Comment: Have you tried it? If it works for you than i can change my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to confirm.

- SQl Server should be `64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (SP1)`
- It's a fresh installation on the server
- Make sure Install account have the required permission on the SQL server and also on the SharePoint Server
- Also Make sure that All pre-req installed properly.

check this one: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jimriekse/2016/02/12/offline-sharepoint-2016-beta-2-and-earlier-issue-when-not-using-prerequisiteinstaller-exe-with-offline-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

I had almost similar issue. I gave full rights to "WSS_ADMIN_WPG" on "C:\Program Files\ Microsoft Office Server\16.0" and run the wizard again. That actually did the magic.